# Reverse arabic/persian words inside html ruby tags in Firefox

Tags: html, tags, reverse, arabic

If you see the following link, I have the same text inside `<p>` and `<rt>`, but the letters appear in the reverse order in Firefox:

https://jsfiddle.net/xgtj9efm/5/

(Even if you don't know the languages, you can still see that the words look different.)

I'm guessing this is a browser bug (I see the text with no problem in IE, Chrome and Opera).
Would you know how can I possibly fix this?